# How to use a custom key in Crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption, key, crypto++, passphrase

I have a question referring to the encryption code in this question:
[Crypto++ encrypt and decrypt in two different c++ programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000688/crypto-encrypt-and-decrypt-in-two-different-c-programs/27342248#27342248)

If I want to use a custom key/iv, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I want to use a custom key/iv, how can I do this?

Just plug it into a cipher with a mode.  There are plenty of modes to choose from, but you should use an authenticated encryption mode like EAX, CCM or GCM. See [Category:Mode](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Category:Mode) for discussion of the modes in Crypto++.

The code below takes a password or secret, keys a cipher, and then encrypts and encodes a message. Next, it decodes the encrypted message. Finally it prints some of the parameters.

---

```
try {

    // KDF parameters
    string password = "Super secret password";
    unsigned int iterations = 15000;
    char purpose = 0; // unused by Crypto++

    // 32 bytes of derived material. Used to key the cipher.
    //   16 bytes are for the key, and 16 bytes are for the iv.
    SecByteBlock derived(32);

    // KDF function
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<SHA256> kdf;
    kdf.DeriveKey(derived.data(), derived.size(), purpose, (byte*)password.data(), password.size(), NULL, 0, iterations);

    // Encrypt a secret message
    string plaintext = "Attack at dawn", ciphertext, recovered;

    // Key the cipher
    EAX<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
    encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(derived.data(), 16, derived.data() + 16, 16);

    AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter ef(encryptor, new StringSink(ciphertext));
    ef.Put((byte*)plaintext.data(), plaintext.size());
    ef.MessageEnd();

    // Key the cipher
    EAX<AES>::Decryption decryptor;
    decryptor.SetKeyWithIV(derived.data(), 16, derived.data() + 16, 16);

    AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter df(decryptor, new StringSink(recovered));
    df.Put((byte*)ciphertext.data(), ciphertext.size());
    df.MessageEnd();

    // Done with encryption and decryption

    // Encode various parameters
    HexEncoder encoder;
    string key, iv, cipher;

    encoder.Detach(new StringSink(key));
    encoder.Put(derived.data(), 16);
    encoder.MessageEnd();

    encoder.Detach(new StringSink(iv));
    encoder.Put(derived.data() + 16, 16);
    encoder.MessageEnd();

    encoder.Detach(new StringSink(cipher));
    encoder.Put((byte*)ciphertext.data(), ciphertext.size());
    encoder.MessageEnd();

    // Print stuff
    cout << "plaintext: " << plaintext << endl;
    cout << "key: " << key << endl;
    cout << "iv: " << iv << endl;
    cout << "ciphertext: " << cipher << endl;
    cout << "recovered: " << recovered << endl;

}
catch(CryptoPP::Exception& ex)
{
    cerr << ex.what() << endl;
}
```

---

A run of the program produces the following output.

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
plaintext: Attack at dawn
key: 7A8C7732898FB687669CB7DBEFBDD789
iv: 0AA980BABE72797E415C9B8979BF30EF
ciphertext: 197D0BD1A12577393AD1B1696B75D0FC6B8A142CF15B5F887AA965CE75F0
recovered: Attack at dawn
```

---

Even better, use an Integrated Encryption Scheme. Crypto++ provides two of them. The first is [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) which operates over fields of elliptic curse. The second is [Discrete Logarithm Integrated Encryption Scheme](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Discrete_Logarithm_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme), which operates over the field of integers.

There's a number of non-obvious reason why its *"even better"*, but the big one is its [IND-CCA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability). Other, more practical ones include: you ***can't*** reuse a security context because correct use is built into the system; and padding has been removed which greatly simplifies proofs and avoids potential oracles. The system is also predicated on [Discrete Logs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), which makes it a Diffie-Hellman based problem and its believed to be hard everywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answere. I want to decrypt the ciphertext with a c# application. I hope I can decrypted it with the standart methods, if I will use your solution to encrypted the plaintext. I will test it later...